# How to subtract only certain values from one column from other column (with different row number)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling, mutate

I have a dataframe as below

```
df <- data.frame(colname=c('A', 'B','c','D'),
                 corr1=c(5500, 2400, 3900,5600),
                 corr2=c(NA, 1600, 600 ,NA),
                 corr3=c(NA, NA, 1200, NA),
                 corr_final=c(5500,2400,2300,3800))
```

I need the following formulas for my calculation to obtain corr_final.

In this values for corr_final for A and B rows stays the same as corr1. For C and D rows however it changes as per following equations.

corr_final(for C row)=3900-1600 (obtained from B row) corr_final(for D row)=5600-1200 (obtained from B row , corr2)-600(obtained from C row , corr3)

so the output is

```
df <- data.frame(colname=c('A', 'B','c','D'),
                     corr1=c(5500, 2400, 3900,5600),
                     corr2=c(NA, 1600, 600 ,NA),
                     corr3=c(NA, NA, 1200, NA),
                     corr_final=c(5500,2400,2300,3800))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` approach using a `case_when`:

Note: The description of your rule for row D does not correspond to the corresponding values. Assuming you meant `corr2` and `corr3` from row C.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  colname = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  corr1 = c(5500, 2400, 3900, 5600),
  corr2 = c(NA, 1600, 600, NA),
  corr3 = c(NA, NA, 1200, NA)
)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  mutate(corr_final = case_when(
    colname == "C" ~ corr1 - corr2[colname == "B"],
    colname == "D" ~ corr1 - corr2[colname == "C"] - corr3[colname == "C"],
    .default = corr1
  ))
#>   colname corr1 corr2 corr3 corr_final
#> 1       A  5500    NA    NA       5500
#> 2       B  2400  1600    NA       2400
#> 3       C  3900   600  1200       2300
#> 4       D  5600    NA    NA       3800
```

Comment: thank you very much for your input. I need one more favor, in this code in case when case, would it be possible to include multiplication as well. For example multiply corr1 by number 1.01 and corr2 by some number 1.2. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sure could we multiply, i.e. inside `case_when` you could do e.g. `colname == "C" ~ 1.01 * corr1 - 1.2 * corr2[colname == "B"]` if that is what you have in mind.